# preg_match php with brackets and determined string is not working

Tags: php, regex

Hi why is the preg_match with brackets and determined string is not working?

Pls let me know your solution to search for "uRole('Admin')".

```
<?php
    $check ='if(uRole("Admin")||uRole("Design")){';
    
    preg_match('/uRole("Admin")/i', $check)? echo 'match':"";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Two reasons** this isn't working...

1. You have to escape `()` in REGEX (otherwise it's assuming a group)
2. You don't use `echo` in a ternary operator; it has to come before

   ```
   echo (STATEMENT_TO_EVALUATE = [TRUE | FALSE]) : TRUE_VALUE : FALSE_VALUE;
   ```

**Working code**

```
$check ='if(uRole("Admin")||uRole("Design")){';
    
echo preg_match('/uRole\("Admin"\)/i', $check, $matches) ? "match" : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `(` and `)` is a [special character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) in regular expressions used to create [groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Because it is a special character, you should use a backslash to escape it:

```php
if (preg_match('/uRole\("Admin"\)/i', $check)) {
    echo 'match';
}
```

By the way, in this situation a simple [`stripos`](https://php.net/stripos) is probably more appropriate:

```php
if (stripos($check, 'uRole("Admin")') !== false) {
    echo 'match';
}
```